# 'depends on' in Spring java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am learning spring and doing some R&D.

i tried 'dependson' concept.

```
<bean id='example1' class='com.freelancing.SpringExample.Example1'
    depends-on="example">
    <!-- <property name="personExample"> <value>sparsh</value> </property> -->
    <property name="age">
        <value>25</value>
    </property>
    <property name="listVariable">
        <list>
            <value>3434</value>
            <value>3432423</value>
            <value>34324324</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="setVariable">
        <set>
            <value>45</value>
            <value>45</value>
            <value>23432</value>
        </set>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id='example' class='com.freelancing.SpringExample.Example'>
    <!-- <constructor-arg index='0'> <value>2345</value> </constructor-arg> 
        <constructor-arg index='1'> <value>sparsh</value> </constructor-arg> -->
    <property name="roll">
        <list>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>3</value>
            <value>5</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="salary">
        <value>12345</value>
    </property>
    <property name='uname'>
        <value>nane</value>
    </property>
    <property name="ex1" ref="example1"></property>
</bean>
```

Now in this code you can clearly see that intentionally i made Example1 class dependson Example. But in Example bean it needs Example1 obj. which is kind of circular dependency.But it is not giving me this error.

Please help me out with some explanation.

Comment: I would prefer using Java Configuration over XML at this point unless you have a dependency on legacy spring. You can use @DependsOn

Comment: Why? Personally, I still prefer XML configuration, for example, since it's still fully supported. Never really found a good argument to switch to java configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Spring can resolve circular dependencies when you are using them in properties. In this case, it can first create an `example` (because example1 depends on it), then create an example1 and then set the `example1` into the field "`ex1`" of the `example` object.

This wouldn't work if you required the example1 in the constructor instead, of course. This is why I personally prefer constructor injection, as it prevents you from having circular dependencies in the first place (they tend to be a sign of bad code).

So, Injection via getter methods (or @`Autowired`) allows spring to resolve circular dependencies, but if you ask me, this is not automatically a good thing, it just hides the fact that some piece of code is bad.